# Компиляция cpuminer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, makefile

Проблема в следующем:

- компилирую на ubuntu 14.4
- переношу бинарник на четыре машины с debian
- на одной нормально стартует на оставшихся выдает следующую ошибку:

> error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open  shared object file: No such file or directory

либо `libcrypto.so.` с другим номером

Подскажите, можно ли скомпилировать бинарник, чтобы в нем были все нужные библиотеки и зависимости?

Компилирую следующим образом:

```
sudo apt-get install -y git automake  pkg-config build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev
git clone https://github.com/wolf9466/cpuminer-multi
cd cpuminer-multi
./autogen.sh
./configure CFLAGS= --with-crypto --with-curl
make
```

Также и на debian пробовал компилировать, ситуация не поменялась.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно. Для этого надо собирать статикой. Для этого сначала запускаем `./configure --help` и смотрим, не предлагают ли нам этого уже. `CFLAGS=" -static"` перед конфигурацией или мейком тоже может помочь. Ну и поставить нужную версию всех библиотек, тоже вариант.

Answer (score 1):

**Проблема**

Для этого придется сначала собрать статически все-все библиотеки, от которых зависит ваш бинарник, а также библиотеки, от которых зависят библиотеки, от которых зависит бинарник и так, пока они не исчерпаются.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Есть решение**

Именно для этого и придумана контейнерная виртуализация! Соберите из вашего бинарника Docker-образ, (это совсем не сложно), распространите его по вашим серверам и разверните. В образ войдут все нужные версии всех библиотек.

**Примерный процесс создания образа**

1. Вы выбираете базовый образ, на основе которого будете собирать ваш майнер. Выбирайте что-то, что вам хорошо известно, например, `fedora:25`.
2. Вы пишите `Dockerfile`, в котором перечисляете команды на установку и сборку вашего бинарника внутрь контейнера на базе выбранного образа.
3. Остается распространить ваш `Dockerfile` на все машины. По инструкциям из него, они сами скачают базовый образ, затащат в него нужные пакеты, соберут майнер и запустят его.

Answer (score 0):

Не всё так печально :-) Раз Вы устанавливали эту программу, на все четыре компа, то это означает, что у Вас там есть права админа.

Поскольку библиотека  *libcrypto.so* входит в состав пакет *libssl1.0.0* то достаточно только установить этот пакет. Если Вы сделаете это пакетным менеджером, отслеживающим внешние зависимости, то никаких дополнительных проблем не возникнет. Например, вот так:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

ЕМНИП, ./configure --disable-shared включит статическую сборку